# Photoshop CC - Use one Layer in different groups with different effects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have designed the background picture for our company phones.
It changes slightly with seasons and on special occasions.

What I would like to do:
have one layer (eg with numbers for ambulance an police) linked to multiple layer groups (lets say they are called "summer", "autumn", "soccer em 2016"). In these groups I want to assign blending styles, masks and even rotate this layer.
So when I update the text in this layer it's updated in any "copy" but with it's distinctive "styles" of the layer group and I do not have to redo all steps i did before.
Example: in the summer layer the text is unmodified. In the "autumn layer" i need a mask so an additonal layer with flying leafs looks like as if some leafs are before and others are behind the text. In the "soccer em 2016" i need to rotate and re-position the text slightly so it looks like a soccer playing is shooting it through the phone.

is this possible?
If not, how would you solve this?

Comment: Use can use [Smart Objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html).

Answer (score 1):

Like CAI already mentioned in a comment:

1. Create a Smart Object out of this layer.
2. Copy it
3. Whenever you edit the Smart Object, all copies will be updated as well.
4. Layer effects, blending modes, opacity etc. will stay the same.